retrofit async call inside interceptor
I have a requirement to make some async call inside the interceptor, the response of the request is not relevant to the call but I dont want to block the ongoing request/response. I tried to make the interceptor as passthrough but unfortunately throwing illegal state exception, any help would be appreciated.
eg:
val request = chain.request()
val response = proceed()
//async tracking
I tried with thread here but it's throwing illegal state exception
return response

you can use runBlocking. As mentioned in the documentation, it "Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread until its completion."
For example:
val resp = runBlocking {
    // asynchronous operation
}

When used inside an interceptor like that, the interceptor continues its work after the asynchronous operation is completed.
You can learn more details from the following document:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html

I don't want to block the interceptor... This call result not relevant to the ongoing request
